# Primeflex Flexgrid support for IE11? any workaround to get the flexgrid working on IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, primeng, msflexgrid, primeflex

The columns alignment using "p-dir-col" does not display as expected in IE11.

To reproduce, check out the demo page opened in Internet Explorer 11:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/flexgrid

=> There are no space between each row in IE, while the columns are correctly displayed in Chrome for instance.

[On IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dllfq.png)

[On other browsers e.g chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmljj.png)

Answer (score 1):

I try to visit the PrimeNG site and try to check that example using Chrome and IE 11 browser.

I made some tests with it and find that issue caused by **flex-basis**

I check the documentation and I find information below.

> When a non-auto flex-basis is specified, Internet Explorer 10 and 11
>   always uses a content-box box model to calculate the size of a flex
>   item, even if box-sizing: border-box is applied to the element.

Reference:

[Flex basis Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis#Browser_compatibility)

Here, if you check the value of **flex-basis** on that grid using developer tools than you can find that it is set as **0px**

[image]

To fix the issue for IE browser, you need to set **flex-basis: auto** like below.

```
flex-basis:auto;
```

Testing result in IE 11:

[image]

As a work around, user can create their custom CSS classes and use for grid to display properly in IE because user cannot make any changes in third party utility.